# How to migrate code 'BeginCheckpoint/RollbackCheckPoint/CommitCheckPoint' in DevForce 2012?

Tags: devforce

We try to migrate our application from DevForce Classic to 2012.
   In old code,   if it tries to save data both in parent window and child window together (child view is displayed when clicking button in parent window),  it invokes PersistenceManager.BeginCheckpoint() when child window is displayed and invokes RollbackCheckPoint/CommitCheckPoint if user click OK/Cancel button.
  It seems it doesn’t have function in EntityManager.
  Is similar function supported by DevForce 2012?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DevForce 2012 does not include the checkpointing feature.  You can accomplish this UOW-type behavior using a separate EntityManager for actions performed in the child window, and then merge any changes back into a "main" EntityManager.  You might also be interested in [Cocktail](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/cocktail), an adjunct to DevForce which includes built-in UOW support, among other features.